# Unit Testing ASP.NET MVC with Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, integration-testing, mdf

We have an insanely data driven application.  We want to unit test the application but developers are resistant to building entirely fake repositories because of the volume of data.  I don't really blame them.

Understand that we are retrofitting tests into an existing application.  If we were starting over we would make a ton of architectural changes to facilitate better unit testing with fake repositories.

We would like to distribute a known mdf file with the tests, copy it, and use that for performing our tests.  Is there an approved technique for this?  I'm familiar with embedding resources into the test dll, but not with embedding mdf's--if that can even be done.

---

A solution (sort of):

I ended up taking the DataContextWrapper from Andrew Tokeley's post on mocking Linq data contexts (http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/07/06/mocking-linq-to-sql-datacontext.aspx)
and created a FakeDataContext.cs that is basically a bunch of Lists.

I wrote a truly barbaric T4 template (think "select * FROM <#=table.BaseClass.QualifiedName#>") to copy the data from a known good database to create a huge class full of stuff like:

```
List<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>();
_customers.Add(new Customer(){CustomerId = 1, CustomerName = "ACME"});
```

etc.

The class is 25K lines but since t4 writes all those lines, who cares?  It allows us to mock just the data context, so we can test our linq against the fake context with some reasonable assurance we got the queries right.  The original devs put a ton of business logic in the repo, so it allows us to test the logic against known good data.

Comment: What you are looking for is a way to do Integration Tests, which @Jakub has provided a good answer for.  What testing framework are you using?

Comment: Vanilla VS 2010 to drive our unit (small integration?) tests.  Stuff like: does the membership layer correctly lock an account after 5 bad passwords?.  That, and a bunch of Selenium to verify the whole mess works soup to nuts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you set up a test database on a shared server so you don't have to deploy mdf files?

Also, can you wrap all unit tests with TransactionScope?

I've used a test database in my company that contained an well known reference data for all the tests and created a base class for integration tests like that:

```
[TestClass]
public class ServiceTest
{
    private TransactionScope Transaction { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void TestInitialize()
    {
        Transaction = new TransactionScope();
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public virtual void TestCleanup()
    {
        Transaction.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Each test will rollback all it's changes so there's no problem with test data polluting the database.

Comment: Technically speaking, these would be called "Integration Tests".  This is the approach I use in my projects, and it works great!

Comment: It should also be noted that xUnit provides a built-in way to do this: http://xunit.codeplex.com/

Comment: We do this. I'd recommend this approach over fake repositories. Would you want to fake a 10,000 line stored procedure? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at a mocking framework? If you're code is written in such a way that data dependencies can be injected in to the objects you're unit testing then you should be able to mock those data dependencies.

I have had great success with Moq, but then I wrote my code with dependency injection from the outset.

Comment: Brian mentioned that the app is heavily data driven - I suppose mocking (a great practice) might not be very feasible. I used to work on the app that used so much data from the database and the logic was spread across so many classes / services that it would be impossible to mock it without rewriting it first ;-)

Comment: Yeah, its a mess.  We do use moq where we can, but the quantities of fake data are just insane.  We are injecting the data dependencies, but the fake repositories are just getting huge.